# R shiny seq instruction error length.out

Tags: r, shiny, seq

I'm beginner and I wrote a short code for my first shiny application following a youtube tutorial.

I get the following error: argument **'length.out' must be of length 1**

There are two R scripts the first one is:

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input,output){
output$distPlot<-renderPlot({ 
x<-faithful[,2]
bins<-seq(min(x),max(x),length.out=input$bins)
hist(x,breaks=bins,col="darkgray",border="white")
})
})
```

The second file:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(titlePanel("Shiny
Application"),sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel("bins","number of
bins",min=1,max=60,value=30),
mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot")))))
```

I checked intruction several times and search in help information but I cant find what is the problem, some advice or help?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't create an input element for `bins`. You probably want a `numericInput()`. A `sidebarPanel()` doesn't work like you seem to be assuming it does.

Comment: Thanks for the help, changing the way you suggest works. I guess I have to check again how to implement a side bar for make the application run.

Answer (score 0):

library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(titlePanel("Aplicacion"), sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(sliderInput("bins", "bins",
                                                                                                min = 1, max = 60, value = 30)),
mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot")))))